# Getting error while adding React Testing Library for create-react-app (version 16.12.0)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, react-testing-library, react-testing

I'm working on a react project in typescript (react version 16.12.0) and I would like to add React Testing Library to this. The newer versions of react comes with React-Testing-Library but the project I'm working on doesn't come with RTL, so I installed it manually.

I added the below to package.json and did yarn install

```
"@types/testing-library__react": "^10.2.0",
```

When I did yarn start, I get this error below

[image]

**Other related packages versions used**

```
 "@types/react": "~16.9.14",

 "typescript": "3.4.5",

 "react-scripts": "^3.0.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was occurring with the typescript version. After some research, I found that for react-testing-library to work with `typescript`, the TS version needs to be updated to 3.8 and above.

After updating `typescript` version to `3.8` and fixing some of the errors caused by this update, I was able to resolve this error.